# useEffect React

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Правильно ли я понимаю? Функция которая возвращается внутри UseEffect, она кроме очистки предыдущего UseEffect, может и изменять предыдущий UseEffect, к примеру тут объявлена переменная "close" функция которая возвращается она как бы грубо говоря лазит в предыдущий useEffect и изменяет значение этой переменной?

```
useEffect(() => {
    let close = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (!close) {
        console.log('Старый', close);
        return;
      }
      console.log('Текущий', close);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      close = false;
    };
  }, [count]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Типа того, у неё та же область видимости что и у кулбека который передается в useEffect(). То есть она видит переменную `close` и в ней можно менять значение этой переменной. Рекомендую почитать про область видимости и замыкания, что бы понять подробнее как это работает.